# Yii selecting only specified attributes and to JSON

Tags: php, yii

I want only show the specified attributes to client, but json string included **NOT specified** attributes.

$data = Music::model()->findAllByPk($musics, 
    array(
       **'select'=>'id, song',** 
    ...
    )
);

But json encode string is:

```
[{id: x, song:'xxx', uid: null, disabeld: null}, ...]
```

I don't want these fields (uid, disabeld) show to user, It's not secure.

I try use these but not working:

```
CJSON::encode();
FOREACH()... getAttributes();
```

Sorry for my EN bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a listData with the fields that you want, and this listData (array) encode to JSON:

```
    $data = Music::model()->findAllByPk($musics, array( 'select'=>'id, song', ... ) );
    $musicList = CHtml::listData($data, 'id', 'song');

    CJSON::encode($musicList);
```

Comment: Thanks, i find foreach($musics as &$music){ $music = $music->getAttributes(false); } can do this.